# Need help loading a git-completion.bash file

Tags: git, git-completion

I am new to git. Every time I try loading my  `git-completion.bash` I got the following error message

```
line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
-bash: git-completion.bash: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You accidentally saved the HTML representation of the file from GitHub (https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) instead of the file itself.
You should save the **raw** file instead - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash .